# Неизменное положение элмента

Tags: html, css

При наведении на элемент hover хотелось бы реализовать, чтобы блок link оставался на месте, а не смещался вниз

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; 
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.content:hover .hide {
  display: block;
}

.link {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
  <div class="link">
  <a href="">
    link
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `position:absolute`

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; 
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  position:relative;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background:inherit;
  margin:0;
  padding:1em 0;
}
.content:hover .hide {
  display: block;
}

.link {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
  <div class="link">
  <a href="">
    link
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
```